# How to use CSOM/Powershell to update list item(s) in O365 from CSV

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, client-object-model

Not a programmer, but need to get a job done.

Using Powershell and CSOM I've found examples and been able to import CSV into a list as new items. That is working. Here is a code snippet I'm using that comes after I already got the list:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$web = $context.Web
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation]$itemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation;
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$item = $list.AddItem($itemCreateInfo);
$item["Title"] = $row.Title; ..... etc.
```

This works great to add new items to the list. However, now I need to update existing items in the list and can't seem to find any examples specific to what I'm using. Seems like it might be the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeItem, but I don't know how to use it.

Examples from MSDN, [ChangeItem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changeitem%28v=office.15%29.aspx) etc show C# and VB. Thanks if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 7):

As an introductory please follow [How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks) article to get acquainted with how to update a SharePoint list item via CSOM.

### How to update list items via CSOM in PowerShell

Assume the following data is contained in CSV file

```
ID,FullName,Company,Title
1,Pilar Ackerman,Contoso Ltd,Manager
2,Jonathan Haas,Contoso Ltd,Finance Specialist
```

Then, the following script could be used to update list item(s) in Contacts list

```
Function Update-ListItem([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$List,$ID, $Properties)
{
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$context = $List.Context
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$listItem = $List.GetItemById($ID) 
    foreach($p in $Properties.psobject.Properties) {
       if($p.Name -eq "ID")  {
           continue
       }     
       $listItem[$p.Name] = $p.Value  
    }
    $listItem.Update()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
}

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)

$data = Import-Csv "c:\upload\Contacts.txt"
foreach ($row in $data) {
   Update-ListItem -List $list -ID $row.ID -Properties $row 
}
```

Key points:

- `ID` field is used for getting an existing list item

Comment: Super answer Vadim! This is a very good example of how to answer a SP.SE question! Thanx for all the great work you put in here!

Comment: Thank you Benny for the kind words and being a great contributor and moderator here in SP.SE!